# Memory question on Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite, memory

Im currently using [WP-Memory-Usage plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-memory-usage/) on my wordpress multisite network to monitor my memory usage. The memory usage displays **39.1 MByte**. Does it mean **39.1 MByte** per blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this has to do with each page load and uses PHP's [memory_get_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) plugin.

Every page load will have a slightly different memory usage. Disabling plugins will decrease it, as the plugin doesn't have to load on that page.

This means that the usage will be different on every blog, and possibly on different pages in the blog.

Comment: So each page load it may use 39.1mbyte.. so it means that when blog 1 loads with about 30mbyte memory and blog 2 loads the same time as blog 1 with about 32mbyte also, both blogs equal to 62 mbyte right?

Comment: Ken: Yes and no. That view is too simplistic. Modern web servers use shared memory spaces, so the total footprint for the PHP process may be shared, or it may not be, or it may be spinning off several long running PHP processes to use for timesharing (the FastCGI method), or one of any of a dozen different things. There's no way to use the knowledge of the total memory use within the PHP process alone to infer anything meaningful about how the outside system is treating it or where the memory is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the plugin displays the total memory being utilized by PHP and WordPress (as a whole, i.e. includes theme, plugins) at that point of time. I suggest checking out Alex Rabe's (plugin author) [blog post about the plugin](http://alexrabe.de/2009/06/14/dear-hoster-we-need-more-memory/).